# how to make navigation dropdown menu in Pyro CMS

Tags: php, mysql, pyrocms, dropdown

I have file "header.html" in partial folder, here my code

```
        <ul class="sf-menu" id="mainMenu">
        {{ shoesmart:showMenu group="header" indent="tab"}}
        <li><a href="{{ url }}" class="{{ class }}">{{ name }}</a>
            {{ if children }}
            <ul>
            {{ children }}
                <li><a href="{{ url }}">{{ name }}</a></li>
            {{ /children }}
            </ul>
            {{ endif }}
        </li>
        {{/shoesmart:showMenu}}
        </ul>
```

and I have file "shoesmart.php" in plugins folder, here my code :

```
function showMenu()
{
$return = '';

$menu_list = $this->db->select('*,CONCAT(pua.type,"/",pua.keyword) as path',false)
         ->from('menu mn')
         ->join('product_url_alias pua','mn.url_alias_id=pua.url_alias_id','LEFT')
         ->where('status',1)
         ->get()
         ->result_array();

foreach ($menu_list as $result) {
    $return[] = array(
        'name'  => $result['name'],
        'url'   => BASE_URL.'home/'.$result['path']
        );
}
return $return;
}
```

and my table name in database is "default_menu" that have structure:

```
menu_id     url_alias_id    name    status  parent_id
1           868             Men     1       0
2           869             woman   1       0
```

but when I refresh in browser, just show main menu, its mean that the submenu didn't show. Should I change my code ? or I also add new table for submenu in my database ?So please help me .. I have deadline project tomorrow T.T